# Logic - Need to find overlapping ranges of numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, logic

Say I have an array of "numbers" object with a "startNo" integer and "endNo" integer.

There can be multiple "numbers" in the array and I want to get a new array with modified objects which will only have the ranges with no overlap.

For eg: if the array has:

```
number
( startNo:1 endNo:3)
( startNo:1 endNo:7)
( startNo:2 endNo:9)
( startNo:15 endNo:18)
( startNo:50 endNo:60)
( startNo:55 endNo:65)
```

I want to get an array like this:

```
number
( startNo:1 endNo:9)
( startNo:15 endNo:18)
( startNo:50 endNo:65)
```

I have been trying hands on different approaches with structs, fors and everything but all I get is multi-level-confusion.

I am working on objective-C platform if that helps

**To add: The startPage can be a big number and endPage can be a small number.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//It's written in C# language. But concept can be implemented in any programming language.

```
public class Range
{
    public int startNo { get; set; }
    public int stopNo { get; set; }

    public Range(int start, int stop)
    {
        startNo = start;
        stopNo = stop;
    }
}

        public void GetUniqueRanges()
    {
        var rangeList = new List<Range>();
        rangeList.Add(new Range(7,4));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(3, 15));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(54, 35));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(45, 60));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(60,75));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(76,100));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(6,10));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(16,24));
        rangeList.Add(new Range(19,34));

        var sorted = new List<Range>();
        foreach (var range in rangeList)
        {
            var item = new Range(Math.Min(range.startNo, range.stopNo), Math.Max(range.startNo, range.stopNo));
            sorted.Add(item);
        }
        var result = new List<Range>();
        sorted = sorted.OrderBy(x => x.startNo).ToList();
        var counter = sorted.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < counter; )
        {
            var item = new Range (sorted[i].startNo, sorted[i].stopNo );
            var j = i + 1;
            for (; j < counter; j++)
            {
                if (sorted[j].startNo <= item.stopNo)
                {
                    item.stopNo =Math.Max(item.stopNo, sorted[j].stopNo);
                }
                else
                {

                    break;
                }
            }
            i = j;
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it was aksed in objective c not in java or c#. NSFeaster can not convert c# API's to objective c.

Comment: Hi Vijay, Thanks a lot. Although this is C#, but I get the logic. This solution is the most compact and has less loop-throughs so I'll accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's a classical algorithms course question..

Sort the arrays by descending order of the first (smallest) value.
keep track of two variables: start segment,end segment.

Every turn pick an array and check for start and end numbers and figure out if its
in the segment or not.

This way it is possible to find the overlaps

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't get "keep track of two variables"

Comment: As others mentioned above, this is just the boundaries of the segment/Array.

Comment: please see the revised question.

Comment: The solution should be the same, Just sort the arrays and pick them in order (from biggest start number to the smallest).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your class is MyNumbers and is like this :

```
@interface MyNumbers : NSObject
@property NSInteger startNumber;
@property NSInteger endNumber;

- (id)initWithStartNumber:(NSInteger)start withEnd:(NSInteger)end;

@end
```

And the way to merge:

```
- (void)yourMethod{

    MyNumbers *obj1=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:1 withEnd:3];
    MyNumbers *obj2=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:1 withEnd:7];
    MyNumbers *obj3=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:2 withEnd:9];
    MyNumbers *obj4=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:15 withEnd:18];
    MyNumbers *obj5=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:50 withEnd:60];
    MyNumbers *obj6=[[MyNumbers alloc]initWithStartNumber:55 withEnd:65];

    NSArray *array=@[obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5,obj6];
    NSMutableArray *mergedArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:array[0]];

    for (NSInteger index=1; index<array.count; index++) {
        MyNumbers *currentNumber=array[index];
        MyNumbers *previousNumber=array[index-1];

        if (currentNumber.startNumber<=previousNumber.endNumber) {
            previousNumber.endNumber=currentNumber.endNumber;
            [mergedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:mergedArray.count-1 withObject:previousNumber];
        }
        else{
            [mergedArray addObject:currentNumber];
        }
    }

    for(MyNumbers *element in mergedArray){
        NSLog(@"startNo:%d endNo:%d",element.startNumber, element.endNumber);
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
2013-03-14 17:14:05.040 Inheritance[34234:303] startNo:1 endNo:9
2013-03-14 17:14:05.041 Inheritance[34234:303] startNo:15 endNo:18
2013-03-14 17:14:05.041 Inheritance[34234:303] startNo:50 endNo:65
```

Comment: Great answer Anoop. Thanks for the code. The other answer handled the situation where the numbers will be not in incremental order and start number is greater than end number in some of my cases. Thanks for your answer still. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: I solved as per your question. If you have said, that in un-ordered then just one line of extra statement is required in Obj-C. And you tagged as obj-c. Not C#. Anyways it is upto you which is best and what you feel best.

Comment: I guess you're right. Please add that line of code for archiving purposes, and I'll mark your answer as accepted. Please also note that there is also a loophole where if a range of number lies between an existing unit range (for eg: 5-10 and 2- 14) then it will probably fail.. I have not had it run on the machine though. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to solve this:

1. Create a new empty array (let's name it: tmp).
2. Put first array's **startNo** and **endNo** to tmp.
3. Take second array's **startNo** and **endNo**. Then, decide whether they overlap with the ones in tmp or not. *(If they don't overlap, insert both of them at the end of tmp.)*
4. Repeat the steps for every arrays.
5. tmp will now hold the all ranges with no overlap.

Comment: please see the revised question.

Comment: You just need to figure out how to _decide whether they overlap_. Think of the possible cases that could occur.

Answer (score 1):

Just quick idea  not tested :

1.Get the smallest start number say sn and corresponding end no say en.

2.Go on checking next objects if start no is less than sn then ignore the start no . And if end number is greater than en then store new    end number to your en .

3.This will gives you your object .

4.If the start number is greater than en then create a new object to add into the array .

this should work .tell me if you have further problems

Comment: please see the revised question